# Cannot start an existing container with Podman

Tags: containers, oracle-call-interface, podman, runc

I am running Podman version 1.6.2 on Ubuntu 18.04. I am unable to start a container after stopping it.

I run the container with:

```
podman run -d -p 8081:8081 --name nexus -v /opt/nexus-data:/nexus-data sonatype/nexus3
```

And it starts up ok. If I run:

```
podman container stop nexus
podman container start nexus
```

I get an error:

> Error: unable to start container "nexus": container create failed (no
>   logs from conmon): EOF

When run with debug logging I see this in the output:

> DEBU[0000] Initializing event backend journald           DEBU[0000]
>   using runtime "/usr/lib/cri-o-runc/sbin/runc"  WARN[0000] Error
>   initializing configured OCI runtime crun: no valid executable found
>   for OCI runtime crun: invalid argument
>
> DEBU[0000] unmounted container
>   "419f6576ff23328c6445526058c9988aa27a4b69605348230fa26246a522c726" 
>   ERRO[0000] unable to start container "nexus": container create failed
>   (no logs from conmon): EOF

The source image is: 
`docker.io/sonatype/nexus3`

I'm not sure what the "invalid argument" in the logs means. Do I need to pass another argument?

Comment: What version of `podman` are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Loki Arya noted, a bug in the common package was causing the issue. Since Podman for Unbuntu is no longer being hosted at projectatomic ppa, the updates after version 1.6.2 that fixed the bug were not available.

After removing the project atomic ppa and all associated packages, I reinstalled Podman for Ubuntu from its new repository location [here](https://software.opensuse.org//download.html?project=devel%3Akubic%3Alibcontainers%3Astable&package=podman#manualUbuntu)

I've tested Podman (1.7) and it is working great, including the start command

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be problem with the latest version of `conmon` package from [Project Atomic PPA](https://launchpad.net/~projectatomic/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) (v 2.0.3).

I had the same problem and I installed a lower version of `conmon` package (v 2.0.0) from,
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/conmon_2.0.0-1_amd64.deb

This is a package built for Eoan. However, it worked on my Bionic environment and I am able to start my containers again.

Comment: Apparently Podman will no longer be updated on project-atomic PPA. Instead it will be available via https://software.opensuse.org//download.html?project=devel%3Akubic%3Alibcontainers%3Astable&package=podman               See discussion: https://github.com/containers/libpod/issues/4213